# Prototypal inheritance: Object.create vs Object.assign

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am currently reading Kyle Simpson's You Don't know JS, trying to understand the whole prototype pattern.

It says we can achieve prototypal inheritance between Foo and Bar as follows:

```js
      function Foo(name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
      
      Foo.prototype.myName = function () {
        return this.name;
      };
      
      function Bar(name, label) {
        Foo.call(this, name);
        this.label = label;
      }
      
      // here, we make a new `Bar.prototype`
      // linked to `Foo.prototype`
      Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
      
      // Beware! Now `Bar.prototype.constructor` is gone,
      // and might need to be manually "fixed" if you're
      // in the habit of relying on such properties!
      
      Bar.prototype.myLabel = function () {
        return this.label;
      };
      
      var a = new Bar("a", "obj a");
      
      console.log(a.myName()); // "a"
      console.log(a.myLabel()); // "obj a"
```

I understand the link is made in the line

`Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);`

so that Bar's prototype points to an object whose prototype is `Foo.prototype`.

I was wondering why don't we just do this:

`Bar.prototype = Object.assign({}, Foo.prototype);`

We achieve the same result and now we have one level of prototype chain lookup for all methods instead of two.

Comment: How do you figure that the prototype chain is shorter with `Object.assign`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus you can run the snippet with `Object.assign` 

Comment: It might be one level lower, but it's not the same object - changing stuff in `Foo.prototype` will not be reflected on your assigned prototype.

Comment: @destoryer It's not, I agree. But I am saying that it produces the exact same effect of inheritance.

Comment: If you are to add a function on `Foo.prototype`, you would not be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We achieve the same result

No, we don't. `Bar.prototype` would then *not* inherit from `Foo.prototype`, instead it would have its own properties. Sure, the values from `Foo.prototype` would be copied over, but that's just a *snapshot* of `Foo.prototype` from the time `Object.assign` was called instead of a live connection.

Comment: So, would you say it is better to use `Object.assign` when I am not changing for example, `Foo` at runtime? (which I think mostly would be the case if inheritance is my goal).

Comment: No, it would not be better. Copying the properties requires more memory and does not allow engines to optimise method calls like inheritance does.